# Predict actual result after model trained with MinMaxScaler LinearRegression

Tags: machine-learning, python, linear-regression, feature-scaling, mse

I was doing the modeling on the House Pricing dataset. My target is to get the mse result and predict with the input variable

I have done the modeling, I'm doing the modeling with scaling the data using MinMaxSclaer(), and the model is trained with LinearRegression(). After this I got the score, mse, mae, dan rmse result.

But when I want to predict it with the actual result. It got scaled, how to predict the after result with the actual price?

Dataset:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/bsivavenu/house-price-calculation-methods-for-beginners/data

This is my script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error

train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

column = ['SalePrice', 'OverallQual', 'GrLivArea', 'GarageCars', 'TotalBsmtSF', 'FullBath', 'YearBuilt']

train = train[column]

# Convert Feature/Column with Scaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
train[column] = scaler.fit_transform(train[column])

X = train.drop('SalePrice', axis=1)
y = train['SalePrice']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=15)

# Calling LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()

# Fit linearregression into training data
model = model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# Calculate MSE (Lower better)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
print("MSE of testing set:", mse)

# Calculate MAE
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
print("MAE of testing set:", mae)

# Calculate RMSE (Lower better)
rmse = np.sqrt(mse)
print("RMSE of testing set:", rmse)

# Predict the Price House by input:
overal_qual = 6
grlivarea = 1217
garage_cars = 1
totalbsmtsf = 626
fullbath = 1
year_built = 1980

predicted_price = model.predict([[overal_qual, grlivarea, garage_cars, totalbsmtsf, fullbath, year_built]])
print("Predicted price:", predicted_price)
```

The result:

```
MSE of testing set: 0.0022340806066149734
MAE of testing set: 0.0334447655149599
RMSE of testing set: 0.04726606189027147

Predicted price: [811.51843959]
```

Where the price is should be for example 208500, 181500, or 121600 with grands value in $.

What step I missed here?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058774/scikit-learn-how-to-scale-back-the-y-predicted-result): You can undo the scaling with [inverse_transform](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform).

Comment: Hi @Erwan , so can I inverse my `predicted_price`? These value is not actual value. Because, when I tried to inverse it, it got an error. I used this `scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_price)`

Comment: @Erwan My error goes like this `Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`

Comment: Wait, I'm realizing that there are other errors in your code. I'm going to write an answer.

Comment: @Erwan Oh my god! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First, you can't use anything from the test set before training. This means that the scaling should be done using only the test set, otherwise there's a risk of data leakage.
- Then remember that scaling your features means that the model learns to predict *with scaled features*, therefore the test set should be passed after it has been scaled as well (using the same scaling as the training set, of course).
- Finally you could obtain the real price value by "unscaling" with `inverse_transform`. But instead I decided not to scale the target variable in the code below because it's not needed (except if you really want to obtain evaluation scores scaled). It's also simpler ;)

````
full = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

column = ['SalePrice', 'OverallQual', 'GrLivArea', 'GarageCars', 'TotalBsmtSF', 'FullBath', 'YearBuilt']

full = full[column]

X = train.drop('SalePrice', axis=1)
y = train['SalePrice']

# always split between training and test set first
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=15)

# Then fit the scaling on the training set
# Convert Feature/Column with Scaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
# Note: the columns have already been selected
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

# Calling LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()

# Fit linearregression into training data
model = model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

# Now we need to scale the test set features
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_scaled)
# y has not been scaled so nothing else to do 

# Calculate MSE (Lower better)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
print("MSE of testing set:", mse)

# Calculate MAE
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
print("MAE of testing set:", mae)

# Calculate RMSE (Lower better)
rmse = np.sqrt(mse)
print("RMSE of testing set:", rmse)

# ... evaluation etc.
```
````

Comment: Note that I didn't test the code so there can be mistakes.

Comment: Oh my... Your answer really helpful for me to understand, so may I know, when we usually scale the target? Is there any difference in the evaluation score between scaled and non-scaled?

Comment: And also, can you give me an example of evaluation? I'm trying to create the evaluation, but it has an unreasonable value `Predicted price: [741.24570557]`. The input variable I used same as my script `# Predict the Price House by input:`

Comment: As far as I know there's never a technical need to scale the target, this is useful only for features. The only case where this makes sense is if you want to scale the result for other reasons, for example because to make comparisons between different datasets. Evaluation is what you do with MAE or MSE, RMSE. For example MAE is the average error value (difference between predicted and true value) in the test set. Of course the lower the error, the better.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Okay I understand now!